# how to do authentication using saml picketlink in jboss ?

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I am new to saml and xacml.I want to implement authentication using saml.some one told about picketlink in jboss.Can anyone give sample program and how to configure jboss using picketlink.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the documentation from this link

http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/pdf/

I am also new to picketlink.It updated on 20 Aug 2013,I think this is good to start.

Answer (score 1):

The [PicketLink Quickstarts](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/PLINK/PicketLink+Quickstarts) provides some useful examples using PicketLink Federation.

There are 3 basic applications which are customized to several scenarios (e.g. encryption, signatures):

- **idp** - Identity Provider (IdP)
- **sales** - Service Provider using HTTP POST Binding
- **employee** - Service Provider using HTTP REDIRECT Binding

Answer (score 0):

More current information on official [github](https://github.com/picketlink2/picketlink-quickstarts). There and working examples and ready-made applications.